# C#: Why does this not zoom using the mouse as center?

Tags: c#, mouse, zooming, paint

I'm trying to make a canvas where you can zoom and pan. The panning works, but zooming at the mouse position won't work.

**EDIT: This almost works. The center for zoom is slightly offset however...**

This is the code for the zooming:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        PointF mouseDown;

        float newX;
        float newY;
        float zoomFactor = 1.0F;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mouseDown = new PointF(0F, 0F);

            this.panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
            this.panel1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
            this.panel1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics dc = e.Graphics;

            dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            dc.TranslateTransform(newX, newY);
            dc.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);

            Color lineColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200);
            Pen linePen = new Pen(lineColor,1*zoomFactor);

            dc.DrawLine(linePen, 100, 100, 200, 200);

            textBox1.Text = newX.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = newY.ToString();
        }



        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

            if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                mouseDown = mouse.Location;

                mouseDown.X = mouseDown.X - newX;
                mouseDown.Y = mouseDown.Y - newY;

            }

        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

            if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

                float deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X;
                float deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

                newX = deltaX;
                newY = deltaY;

                panel1.Invalidate();

            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                if (zoomFactor + 0.2 < 10)
                {
                    zoomFactor += 0.2F;
                }
            }

            else if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                if (zoomFactor - 0.2 > 0.2)
                {
                    zoomFactor -= 0.2F;
                }
            }

            float x = (mouse.Location.X - newX) * zoomFactor;
            float y = (mouse.Location.Y - newY) * zoomFactor;

            newX = mouse.Location.X - x;
            newY = mouse.Location.Y - y;

            panel1.Invalidate();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, so here's the solution.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    PointF mouseDown;

    float newX;
    float newY;
    float zoomFactor = 1.0F;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mouseDown = new PointF(0F, 0F);

        this.panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
        this.panel1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
        this.panel1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnPaint(e);

        Graphics dc = e.Graphics;

        dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        dc.TranslateTransform(newX, newY);

        dc.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, MatrixOrder.Prepend);

        Color lineColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200);
        Pen linePen = new Pen(lineColor,1*zoomFactor);

        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 100, 100, 200, 100);
        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 200, 100, 200, 200);
        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 200, 200, 100, 200);
        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 100, 200, 100, 100);
        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 100, 100, 200, 200);
        dc.DrawLine(linePen, 200, 100, 100, 200);

    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            mouseDown = mouse.Location;

            mouseDown.X = mouseDown.X - newX;
            mouseDown.Y = mouseDown.Y - newY;

        }

    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            PointF mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

            float deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X;
            float deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

            newX = deltaX;
            newY = deltaY;

            panel1.Invalidate();

        }


    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        PointF mP = mouse.Location;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            if (zoomFactor >= 1 && zoomFactor <= 10)
            {
                zoomFactor += 1F;

                newX = newX - ((mP.X - newX) / (zoomFactor - 1));
                newY = newY - ((mP.Y - newY) / (zoomFactor - 1));
            }
            else if (zoomFactor == 0.5)
            {
                zoomFactor = zoomFactor * 2;
                newX = newX - ((mP.X - newX) );
                newY = newY - ((mP.Y - newY) );
            }
            else if (zoomFactor < 0.5)
            {
                zoomFactor = zoomFactor * 2;
                newX = newX - ((mP.X - newX) );
                newY = newY - ((mP.Y - newY) );
            }
        }

        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            if (zoomFactor >2)
            {
                zoomFactor -= 1F;
                newX = newX + (((mP.X - newX)) / (zoomFactor+1 ));
                newY = newY + (((mP.Y - newY)) / (zoomFactor+1));
            }
            else if (zoomFactor == 2) {
                zoomFactor -= 1F;

                newX = newX + ((mP.X - newX)/2);
                newY = newY + ((mP.Y - newY)/2);
            }else if(zoomFactor <= 1 && zoomFactor > 0.2)
            {
                zoomFactor = zoomFactor / 2;

                newX = newX + ((mP.X - newX) / 2);
                newY = newY + ((mP.Y - newY) / 2);

            }


        }

        panel1.Invalidate();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that still isn't right.  You need to transform screen coordinates where the mouse is into picture coordinates using the OLD zoom factor, then find the new visible left corner using the NEW zoom factor.

Comment: @Ben - it works here by me. I use the transform of the graphics object to transform the graphic. The panel is static and roughly coincides with the form window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MousePosition is different from PanelPosition? I mean on is relative to the control and one relative to the screen?

[Control.PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) is your friend!

Comment: Hmm... it didn't do me any good except i found another small mistake. My panel was offset 30 pixels i y-direction from the form and mousewheel tracks in relation to the form-control, not the panel.